# How to break or exit from With..End With loop in VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript

I am working on exiting VBScript code having with..end with loop.
I need break/exit the loop on a certain condition, how can I break or exit from With..End With loop in VBScript

Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply add `Exit Do` after the condition you are checking.

Comment: Nope. It's not while loop.

Comment: @MrX You're going to have to actually show the code to get any help.  I don't think `With` should be used for a loop in any case, so you will need to explain how you are using it.

Comment: `With` is definitely not a loop construct. Loops in VBScript are various forms of `Do`, `While` or `For` statements.

Answer (score 1):

With is not a looping construct. Something similar to this as an example will work as I credit Lankymart with stating above:

This is designed to loop 10 times but will exit on the If/Then condition of 5 and the Exit Do will execute

```
Do While x < 10
    x = x + 1
    wscript.echo x
    if x = 5 then Exit Do
Loop
```

or...

```
For x = 0 to 10

    x = x + 1
    wscript.echo x
    if x = 5 then Exit For

Next
```